# Viewbag IsValid false while editing/modified data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

I was trying to get my CompanyProfile ID in my UserController
in the first step i get the right ID but in the [HttpPost] the ID value was change into the same value as the user ID
This is my controller

```
public ActionResult Edit (int id)
{
User user = _db.Users.Find(id);
if ( user == null)
{
return HttpNotFound();
}
ViewBag.CompanyProfile = new SelectList(_db.CompanyProfiles,"ID","NamaProfil", user.CompanyProfile.ID);
return View(user);
}


[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Edit(User user)
{
if (ModelState.IsValid)
{
_db.Entry(user).State = EntityState.Modified;
_db.SaveChanges();
return RedirectToAction ("Index");
}
return View(user);
}
```

this is the Model

```
public int ID {get;set;}
public virtual CompanyProfile CompanyProfile {get;set;}
```

and this is the dropdown in the edit view

```
<div class= "controls">
@Html.DropDownList("CompanyProfile", null, "--Choose Company--", new {@class="span6 m-wrap"})
</div>
```

every answer may help,thanks :D

forget to tell this,this is the error message
There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable' that has the key 'CompanyProfile'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a number of issues here. The model you are passing in to your view has a property named CompanyProfile of reference type CompanyProfile. This type cannot be bound to IEnumerable of any kind - those two models simply don't match. Your model property needs to be of type int to match with the selected value you are passing in - user.CompanyProfile.ID.

2nd issue is that you should never name your model property the same as any ViewBag value. Again you have a property named CompanyProfile and you have a ViewBag.CompanyProfile. Those two will be overwriting each other during the model binding...

I suggest you do the following: In your controller bind the select list to a ViewBag without defining the selected value:

```
ViewBag.CompanyProfileList = new SelectList(_db.CompanyProfiles,"ID","NamaProfil");
```

Then your model should have the selected company profile id property:

```
public int CompanyProfileId { get; set; }
```

And then bind it in your view like this:

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.CompanyProfileId, (SelectList)ViewBag.CompanyProfileList, "--Choose Company--", new { @class = "span6 m-wrap" })
```

Comment: but if i didn't define the selected value,my dropdownlist will be null and i can't save the data

Comment: If CompanyProfileId property has a value (let's say 5) and value 5 is one of the values in your select list that you got from _db.CompanyProfiles then the drop down list generated will automatically default to that value as selected.